# Can't find proper name for my table

Tags: database-design, naming-conventions

1) I need to give a name for a table that stores subscriptions id's and credit cards id's (used to renew the subscriptions). The table stores records for credit cards that are about to expire whose users were notified about it already. I find it difficult to name the table properly. Here's the list with my suggestions but i like none of these :)

creditCardNotify, notifiedCreditCards, subscriptionCreditCardNotify

2) One more question. I guess I should rather use the word "notified" instead of "notify" in table name?

Comment: does it really matter? just choose one that is consistent!

Comment: Possible subset of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366479/database-table-naming-name-verb-name-conventions-for-many-to-many-intersect-tab?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't always true, most tables contain records which represent a tangible or intangible *thing*.  Therefore you should try to **use a noun**.

In this spirit, I would suggest something like **creditCardExpiryNotification**.

You didn't ask specifically, but I think it bears saying, that you are better to use **singular nouns**.  You should think in terms of naming the table after the thing a record represents.  This makes it easier to think about your relationships and especially about cardinality and foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Better give the name as renewal_creditcards. It makes a better sense that the credit cards must be renewed

Answer (score 0):

**SubscriptionCCN**

another alternative I like to do is:

**Subscription__CCNotfd**

The `__` representing a cross-walk, or join table.

That way you can easily see when your application grows large where any cross-walk tables reside in a list.